# Can MonoDevelop highlight errors and warnings on-the-fly?

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I'm currently testing MonoDevelop for my hobbist projects needs. It seems like i have to recompile my C# project every time to see if i made some errors in my code. Even simple errors like missing `using` statements aren't shown in the IDE while i'm typing unknown class names.  Did i miss some kind of setting/add-in or this feature is really missing from the IDE?

(I know i can use Alt+Enter on the problematic class to quick add the required `using` statement, but i like to see not just these kinds of errors while i'm typing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonoDevelop does not support background compilation, though it will underline syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you planning to implement background compilation in the future? Can this be done with Mono?

Comment: It's something we'd like to do but there's no ETA at this time.